# python socket bind invalid argument was supplied

Tags: python, sockets, networking

im working on a project that allows me to connect to my client application but when I disconnect the server and then host again the program throws this error:

```
[WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

this is thrown by the socket.bind command:

```
self.Server.bind((str(StrHost),int(IntPort)))
```

I've checked that the StrHost and IntPort are the right values and they are fine. it only happens when I disconnect and re-connect using the server program.

thank you for any help.

Comment: When you disconnect, do you first call `.close()` on the file handle and on then on the socket?

Comment: @mike.k yeah i call the close() function

Comment: Would you mind posting more code from the disconnecting section? I battled a similar problem recently, its still fresh in my head.

Comment: i know why it doesn't work, it was hanging on one of the commands so it wouldn't execute the close command. ill post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so, the reason i had the connection issue is because the program got stuck waiting for a response.
heres the code i was using to connect:

```
def ConnectS(self,IntPort, StrName,E):
    self.BlnCon = False
    StrHost = socket.gethostname()
    self.StrName = StrName
    try:
        self.Server.bind((str(StrHost),int(IntPort)))
    except Exception as Error:
        print(Error)
    self.Connect = socket.socket()
    self.Server.listen(1)
    self.Connect, addr = self.Server.accept()
    self.BlnCon = True
    while self.BlnCon:
        self.RecvMsg(E)
    self.BlnCon = False
    self.Connect.close()
    self.Server.close()
```

if the server disconnected then the function RecvMsg() would still run.
the way to fix this is to have the close method in a separate method.
so you would have a Disconnect function which will just run the 2 close calls.
like this:

```
def Handler(Btn,E,IntZ):
    E.Networking.SendMsg('Exit',E)
    E.Networking.Connect.close()
    E.Networking.Server.close()
    E.Networking.Connect = socket.socket()
    E.Networking.Server = socket.socket()
```

one thing to note in my code is i just added this to a button handler. and I'm not sure but i just set both my variable to socket.socket() just in case it causes issues. i also have the send method to let the other user know that the server has disconnected.

if you want i will post my networking code somewhere (probably github).

Answer (score 1):

According to [MIcrosoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924071.aspx), WinError 10022:

> Invalid argument. Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, >specifying an invalid level to the setsockopt (Windows Sockets) function). >In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket — for >instance, calling accept (Windows Sockets) on a socket that is not listening.

So as mike.k suggested, it does not necessarily mean an invalid argument was supplied (the error message can be misleading).